# The project uses build.properties from another NetBeans installation

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build

When using trying to build a NetBeans project created with a previous version, I get the following confirmation dialog:

[image: Build Project: The project uses build.properties from another NetBeans installation. Build Anyway, Use this installation, Update]

> **Build Project**
>
> The project ... uses build.properties from another NetBeans installation.
>
> - Build Anyway
> - Use this installation
> - Update

What would these options do?

No matter which options I choose, I do not notice any difference in the build process.

Using NetBeans Development with projects created on NetBeans 8.1.

Comment: Did you got why its showing this. Because i have the same issue facing while deploying my project through netbeans.

Comment: I believe this happens when you create a project using some NetBeans version (e.g. 8.1) and then open it using another version (e.g. 8.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on what type of dependencies you are using in your project, to be on safe side , I'd prefer clicking Update which it'll update current project's build properties with the external one,

also here's what (wiki.netbeans.org) have about build.properties file:

"If you edit build.xml by hand, you can of course arrange to build other projects (or any Ant scripts) as part of your build, using the  or  tasks. Note that a build-impl.xml, when building a foreign project, calls its build.xml (rather than skipping to its build-impl.xml), so you can freely mix a hand-customized project with IDE-customized projects."

thanks